# How does readline rl.write work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, readline

I'm trying to parse over a file, and replace lines that say "foobar" with lines that say "bazbar". It just returns an empty file. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and docs aren't being particularly helpful.

```
var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('test/in.txt'),
  output: fs.createWriteStream('test/out.txt', {
    flags: 'r+'
  })
});

rl.on('line', function (line) {
  if (line.match(/foobar/)) {
    rl.write(line.replace(/foo/, 'baz'));
  }
});
```

Here's the tmp repo if anyone is interested in simply pulling and messing with it: https://github.com/corysimmons/css-body-components/tree/master/test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not answer your question, but it accomplishes the task.

I couldn't get `rl.write` to work against a file `WriteStream` but I did get it working by writing directly to the file `WriteStream` instead. Here's the code:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');

var ws = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/test/out.txt', { flags: 'r+', defaultEncoding: 'utf8' })

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/test/in.txt')
});

rl.on('line', function (line) {
  if (line.match(/foobar/)) {
    line = line.replace(/foo/, 'baz');
  }
  ws.write(line + '\n');
});

rl.on('close', function() {
  ws.close()
})
```

#### Edit: `rl.write` will only write to a `TTY`

Looking at the [source for `readline`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v5.6.0/lib/readline.js#L310), Node is checking if the stream provided in `output` is a terminal. If it is, it writes to the stream, if not, it looks like it will re-emit the writes as `line` events.

Which means you must trick the `readline` module into thinking that your `fs.WriteStream` is actually a TTY. Here is some updated code that works. Note line 5 adds an `isTTY` property and sets it to `true`.

```
var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');

var ws =  fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/test/out.txt', { flags: 'r+', defaultEncoding: 'utf8' })
ws.isTTY = true

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/test/in.txt'),
  output: ws
});

rl.on('line', function (line) {
  var ln
  if (line.match(/foobar/)) {
    ln = line.replace(/foo/, 'baz')
  }
  rl.write(ln, '\n')
});
```

Comment: Cool, thank you very much. Now to figure out how to replace the line instead of just appending a line under it. Their docs say `rl.write(null, {ctrl: true, name: 'u'});` should delete the line, but it just floods the file with a ton of weird symbols. Do you happen to know if there's a better way to do this? Perhaps just parse over the entire file and replace stuff?

Comment: Nvm I got it with this https://gist.github.com/corysimmons/a69accfb822e0d76dfce . Thanks again for your help. =)