# Node readline 'line' event not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, promise, readline

I am creating a this program which finds the common words of 2 word files and then creates a new file with just the common words.
I'm using the readline module to read each word of first word file and then store that word in a Trie. After that has been completed, I'm trying to read the words from the other word file and if it is in trie, I'm writing to file.

I'm using promises to make sure that the events happen in sequence but the second time the 'line' event is not triggered.

```
'use strict'
const readLine = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

const wordList = require('./Trie.js');

function createTrie(reader, trie) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(typeof reader === 'undefined' || reader === null)
      reject('Failed')

    reader.on('line', line => trie.add(line))
    reader.on('close', () => {
      console.log('done')
      resolve(trie)
    })
  })
}

function findCommon(reader, trie) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(typeof reader === 'undefined' || reader === null) {
      console.log('failed')
      reject('Failed')
    }

    let commonWords = ''

    console.log('we are here')

    reader.on('line', (line) => {
      console.log(line) // This does not output
      if(line.length > 2 && trie.search(line)) {
        let word = line + '\n'
        commonWords += word
      }
    })
    reader.on('close', () => {
      fs.writeFile('wordlist.txt', commonWords, (err) => {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err)
          reject('error')
        }
        console.log('written')
        resolve('Success')
      })
    })
  })
}

let reader_1 = readLine.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('words/enable2k.txt')
})
let reader_2 = readLine.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('words/engmix.txt')
})

createTrie(reader_1, wordList)
  .then((trie) => findCommon(reader_2, trie))
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
```

The above code gives the below output

```
done
we are here
```

The 'line' event is not triggered. It seems like I'm not using readline correctly but I'm not sure.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you did not set an output stream o.O

Comment: @VictoryOsikwemhe Since I was just reading from the file and not writing to it or setting any prompts for the user, I did not set the output stream. I believe the output stream is optional? :/

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532332/how-does-readline-rl-write-work?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the input stream had closed.
I logged the reader in findCommon function and this was the result(only relevant part)

```
ReadStream {
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 65536,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: true,
        endEmitted: true,
        reading: false,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: false,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _events: { end: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     path: 'words/engmix.txt',
     fd: null,
     flags: 'r',
     mode: 438,
     start: undefined,
     end: undefined,
     autoClose: true,
     pos: undefined,
     bytesRead: 794434,
     destroyed: true,
     closed: true }
```

I modified the call

```
createTrie(reader_1, wordList)
  .then((trie) => findCommon(reader_2, trie))
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
```

to:

```
createTrie(reader_1, wordList)
  .then((trie) => findCommon(readLine.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('words/engmix.txt')
  }), trie))
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
```

This way worked. I'm not sure exactly why this works but it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid promises and callbacks altogether and just execute the logic sequentially using [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs). Logic will transform as follows:

```
var nsynjs = require('nsynjs');
var textFile = require('./wrappers/nodeReadline').textFile; // this file is part of nsynjs

function process(textFile) {

    var fh = new textFile();
    fh.open('path/to/file1');
    var s, dict={};
    while (typeof(s = fh.readLine(nsynjsCtx).data) != 'undefined')
        dict[s] = true;
    fh.close();

    fh = new textFile();
    fh.open('path/to/file2');
    while (typeof(s = fh.readLine(nsynjsCtx).data) != 'undefined')
        if(dict[s])
            console.log(s);
    fh.close();

}

var ctx = nsynjs.run(process,{},textFile,function () {
    console.log('done');
});
```

Code above is based on this example:  https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs/blob/master/examples/node-readline/index.js